# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 122

Tags: mysql, linux, centos7

After i successfully installed mysql on centos 7 i went into mysql -u root -p it came up with this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A4s2.png)

i also tried to solve the problem by mysql including mysqladmin -u root password [newpassword] but this error comes up[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrfW5.png)

Comment: Once you `mysql -u root -p` and click enter it will show `Enter password:`. During that time have you typed any password?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the root password?
Please see the link below.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Otherwise, you could start mysql in safe mode by passing
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
then resetting the root password.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).